# how to reinstall the compiz on Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, compiz

I seems like i have messed up something with my Ubuntu compiz and I am not able to do anything in either Gnome with effects environment not with Unity environments with effect, the environment for both GNOME and Unity without effects work fine, but still I need to fix so that I can use the one with environment with effects, what should I do ?

also does it has to do something with my display drivers? I have NVidia Graphics card

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open Terminal and type

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall compiz compiz-core compiz-gnome compiz-plugins-default compiz-plugins-main-default compizconfig-backend-gconf
```

Then Compiz will be reinstall

Comment: no man , this did not fixed the problem, when I login the one with effects mouse hangs, bar on top doesnt show up properly and menu that has log out freezes when i click on gear icon on top right corner, I rely on keyboard shortcuts to log out that too takes time ...